# Wi-Fi location services not working

Tags: wireless-networking

My iPad no longer knows my location, while at home. Works fine at other Wi-Fi locations. I have TWCable and they say they do not provide location services, or, it's my router. Netgear says router is OK, must be Time Warner Cable. Wife's PC laptop not as accurate as it use to be. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean its not as accurate as it used to be?

Comment: Thinks I am in neighboring city (32 miles away). It use to show my exact location on Honeoye Lake, NY, and does show my exact location at any WiFi outside of my home

Answer (score 0):

If you have any mobile products with GPS (iPhones, iPads with cellular) make sure you haven't opted out of helping improve the accuracy of the OS vendor's location database. For example, Apple products with GPS that haven't opted out will periodically report their GPS location and the BSSIDs of Wi-Fi APs around them to Apple. Then, any Wi-Fi-only Apple devices can figure out their location based on the BSSIDs of the Wi-Fi APs around them.

There's no way to force a GPS-using Apple device to send a location update, and Apple may wait for multiple reports in order to keep people from gaming the system. So there's no quick way to improve the accuracy, you just have to turn it on and leave it on.

Helping improve Apple's database will help your iPad. As for your wife's PC laptop, assuming it's running Windows, Microsoft has a similar database they update a similar way, but in this case you'll need to have GPS-equipped devices running a Microsoft OS. Similar story for Google and Android devices.

If your own Wi-Fi network is the only network in range, and you just replaced your router, there might be a period of time where the various companies' location services databases have no idea where that new BSSID is located, so Wi-Fi-only devices won't be able to figure out where they are. If you move to a new home and take your Wi-Fi router with you, you may end up with Wi-Fi-only devices still thinking they're in the old location for a while.

One time I was at a tech conference in San Francisco and my Wi-Fi-only devices thought I was in Austin. It turns out the company providing the Wi-Fi network for the event had just done SXSW using the same hardware, so the Apple, Google, Microsoft, Skyhook, etc. location databases hadn't yet realized that all those APs were now in San Francisco. By the second day of the conference it had sorted itself out.

Comment: Accuracy problem is on both Wifes pc laptop and my IPAd. wifi router working fine and I have done nothing to it (6 months old).

Comment: Oops I completely skipped the part about your wife's PC laptop. I'll update my answer. The short version is that every major mobile OS vendor has their own database that basically works the same way.